# Working with Drupal views

Tags: php, drupal, view

I have a page that lists all content authors.  What I am having trouble doing is displaying the authors latest article along with all of his other information.  Currently it is displaying his avatar first name last name.  But getting a proper join to display the latest content article or podcast has eluded me.  Is there a way to use the Drupal view module to display the latest article or podcast (node).

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried pux? but only in combination with context module ;) http://drupal.org/project/pux

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7?  Have you used views relationships  yet?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i recomend you to use [views field views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)

you create a new view that show latest article for 1 author with the given contextual filter, then use views field views to embed that view and pass the nid from the autor in that view.
Hope its helps, letme know.